# Create folders as a function parameter in python

Tags: python-3.x, file, mkdir

In this code i am reading multiple folders and sent the files of each folder as input parameter to processing it in  func2(), i need to save the output of processing in new creating folder how can i do that. my problem in this my code is just one folder is created and then the contents of the new folder passes again to func2()!

```
pp=1
directory = "out"+str(pp) 
parent_dir = 'C:\\Users\\lap\\Desktop\\main\\enc\\'
path = os.path.join(parent_dir, directory )   
os.mkdir(path)  
print("Directory '% s' created" %directory)  

input_path = Path(Path.home(), "Desktop", "main")
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_path):
    for file in files:
        file_path = Path(root, file)
        #func(input files, output files)
        cc = func(file_path,'C:\\Users\\lap\\Desktop\\main\\enc\\%s\\' %directory)
        cc.func2()
    pp+=1
```

Comment: instead of \\ you can use `os.sep` which works across different [os]es.

Comment: @arl_de_owl ,please clarify more!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why only one folder gets created is, that the value of the `directory` variable never changes inside the `for` loop. You can add these lines in your code so as to get what you want.

```
...
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_path):
    directory = "out"+str(pp) 
    for file in files:
...
```

Comment: Now it just create folders without use this new folder in function!

Comment: Then I think there is some issue with your `func` method.